# Finding the tangent to a parametric curve $(t^3, t^5)$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: vectors, parametric, tangent-line

The curve $(t^3, t^5)$ at that point $(0,0)$ does not have a tangent vector as when you work it out, you will arrive at $(0,0)$.

**Question:** How can you find a new parametrisation for the curve such that you get a tangent vector at $(0,0)$. Is this even possible.

**My attempts:**

> Changing the curve's position by taking $t \to t+1$ won't work because it just changes the position of the point we're trying to find the tangent on
> A trig sub may be possible, however I have had no luck

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {\frac {dy}{dt}}{\frac {dx}{dt}}$

$\frac {5t^4}{3t^2} = \frac 53 t^2$

As noted the derivative appears to not exist when $t=0$  But, the limit exists.

$\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac 53 t^2 = 0$

$y = 0$

An alternative would be to say

$y^3 = x^5 \\
y = x^\frac 53\\
y' = \frac 53 x^\frac 23$

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question, which, first and foremost, asks if there is a parameterization of the curve which makes it possible to compute the derivative at the origin direclty.  I agree that there are other techniques make it possible, but you seem to have skipped explaining how to find such a parameterization, or why no such parameterization exists.

Answer (score 1):

$(0,0) $ is a singular point.
but

$$t^3=0+0t+0t^2+t^3+0t^4+0t^5+t^5\epsilon(t)$$
and
$$t^5=0+0t+0t^2+0t^3+0t^4+t^5+t^5\epsilon(t)$$
so

$(0,0)$ is an inflexion point with $\vec{i}=(1, 0) $ as the tangent vector.